# Output values based on day

Tags: php

I have a PHP loop that generates days of the week.

```
$wk = array(1 => "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

foreach ($wk as $k => $v) {
    ...
}
```

That produces something like this:

```
Monday
 ... additional HTML code here

Tuesday
 ... additional HTML code here

Wednesday
 ... additional HTML code here
```

I also have another query that outputs the data into an array **$items** in the following array format:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [day] => 2
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:32:52
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [day] => 3 
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:19
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [day] => 3
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:23
    )

)
```

There problem I'm having is with the array. There's a value that corresponds to the week day. For example: [day] => 3 corresponds to $k == 3 (Tuesday).

How do I output the data from my object into the slots corresponding to the days of the week? I could run a separate query for each day, but that seems a bit inefficient and the caffeine has not quite kicked-in yet...

Comment: With 3k rep you should know that this "question" is of very poor quality! You are a 4 year member, if you can't solve such problems after 4 years of practice, then probably nobody can help you at all?

Comment: yeah question is a little bit unclear, but from what I can gather, why not just stick in a counter in your for each loop? Then just use an if statement to check if the day is correct?

Comment: @hek2mgl My 3K came mostly from asking good questions over years... Any help with PHP though or you never had such moments where the "obvious" is in front of you?

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate over `$items`
- Fetch value from `$items[]->day`
- Use it as an index for `$wk`

Something like this should work if I understand your question correctly:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $wk[$item->day];

    // Or if you want to update it
    $item->day = $wk[$item->day];
}
```

**OR** if you want to keep your original loop (`foreach ($wk as $k => $v)`), index your query results on the `day` key so your array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        // objects of that day
    ),
    [4] => Array
    (
        // etc
    )
)
```

You can then alter your original foreach-loop:

```
foreach ($wk as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($items[$k] as $item) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to restructure my array?.. Or do i run a separate loop under each week day and only select values that correspond to the day number? Arrays always get me... I can not touch my week days structure as it has additional code attached to it.

Comment: Index your query result on the `day` key and keep your original foreach-loop. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I definitely need to keep in touch my original loop for the days of the week. There's a lot of additional HTML, JS and PHP code already there. I just need to insert additional data from the $items array.