# Reorder a multidimensional array containing objects

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a large array object that looks something like this:

```
$items = Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [day] => 2
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:32:52
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [day] => 3 
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:19
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [day] => 3
        [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:23
    )

)
```

I need to restructure it in such a way that I could output results based on a day value. For example all records associate with day = 3 and so on.

I already have a structure of code that is based on days of a week, so I need to run a separate loop for this array to insert the records that match each day of the existing structure.

For example:

```
$wk = array(1 => "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

foreach ($wk as $k => $v) {
   ...
   // insert records from $items 
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite my $items array to accomplish this? If yes, how? Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create new array
- iterate over old array
- create index in new array if it doesn't exist
- add item of old array to new index

Something like this should work:

```
// Create new array
$daySortedItems = array();

// Iterate over old array
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Create index in new array if it doesn't exist
    if (! isset($daySortedItems[$item->day])) {
        $daySortedItems[$item->day] = array();
    }

    // Add item of old array to new index
    $daySortedItems[$item->day][] = $item;
}
```

Hope that this, in combination with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528361/output-values-based-on-day/26528539), solves your problem. Do note that throwing hot-fixes in like this is considered bad practice. A better solution is to fix the problem at a lower level: when querying the database, index the result set on the `day` key directly.

Comment: It produced: Array
(    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [day] => 3
                    [created] => 2014-10-22 21:32:52
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [day] => 3
                    [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:19
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [day] => 3
                    [created] => 2014-10-22 21:35:23
                )

Comment: Sorry, I had to abbreviate due to allowed comment length, but in general I could not see how I could use it to match data to associated dates... This is just an example, but there could be a lot more records for each day.